# Comparing strings with special characters using if-loop does not work

Tags: shell, quoting, test

I want to compare each line of a particular file with the following string

```
#orb_plugins = ["local_log_stream", "iiop_profile", "giop", "iiop"];
```

("file.txt" contains this particular line)

I tried the following by prefixing special characters with '\'

```
IFS=''
while read -r line
do
  if [ "$line" == "#orb_plugins = \[\"local_log_stream\", \"iiop_profile\", \"giop\", \"iiop\"\];" ]
  then
    echo "String found. Do remaining steps"
  fi
done < file.txt
```

Comment: You are trying to define an array there, but then you do not use it, I *think*. Would not be easier to use a case statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple method is to use single quotes on the right hand side:

```
if [ "$line" == '#orb_plugins = ["local_log_stream", "iiop_profile", "giop", "iiop"];' ]
```

This way the string to be matched is interpreted literally.

If you prefer using double quotes, you must not escape the brackets (`[]`), but only the double quotes (`""`):

```
if [ "$line" == "#orb_plugins = [\"local_log_stream\", \"iiop_profile\", \"giop\", \"iiop\"];" ]
```

Comment: Using single quotes solves the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Why not using the right tool for this job, i.e. `grep`:

```
grep -qxFf- file.txt <<\IN && printf %s\\n "String found. Do remaining steps"
#orb_plugins = ["local_log_stream", "iiop_profile", "giop", "iiop"];
IN
```

This stops reading the file as soon as a match is found. It's also (on average) about 100 times faster than your `while read` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is just part of my 100 line code. I am not skilled enough to use grep/sed instead of using grep in all places.
As you mentioned, the script runs too slow.